# Link SMS OTP authentication with Email link verification authentication in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am using two authentication methods with firebase , phone authentication and email link verification authentication. 
However both lead to separate accounts, I somehow want to connect email to account verified using phone , so that next time when email link authentication is used correct account ( linked via phone ) is retrieved.

I could find https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking but this doesn't mention about link verification method.

What I am thinking here is , when user logs in using phone , can I add email to the users profile on firebase auth, so that same email can be used for email verification.

Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the solution what i did was as follows .
I first now authenticated user using phone , when OTP is verified instead of calling signInWith method I asked user if he wants to link an email with this phone. If user opts in and enters email , a verification link goes to his email account when user performs email verification , after returning to app I am linking this verified email with the phone authenticated account using the link.
I already have the dynamic links working , so used it here as it is.